# MS Unit Tests not discovered in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

Why are my  unit tests are not discovered in the Test Explorer ? I am using Visual studio 2017.Initially it was but now i cannot see them in the test explorer any more.

Here is the code snippet of what i was trying out -

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
    private Result _response;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
       _response =  SetupMockData();           
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void it_should_get_all_objects ()
    {
        _response.MockObject.ToList().Count().Should().Be(3);
    }}
```

Comment: Try to clean the solution and rebuild.

Comment: I suspect you may have forgotten to include the contents of test file in your posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the reference to the MSTest.TestAdapter nuget was missing in my test project. Added it and the unit tests were discoverable. Yipee!